# Subclass NSManagedObject to easy initialize

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

For my models from server API i use constructor like that:

```
@implementation MenuAPIModel

-(instancetype)initWithServerData:(id)data{

    self = [super initWithServerData:data];
    return self;
}

-(void)performMapping{

    _basketId = self.serverData[@"basket_id"];
    _orderId = self.serverData[@"order_id"];
    _itemId = self.serverData[@"id"];
    _name = self.serverData[@"name"] == [NSNull null] ? @"" : self.serverData[@"persons"];
    _payedFrom = [self.dfDetail dateFromString:self.serverData[@"payed_from"]] == nil ? [self.dfBasic dateFromString:self.serverData[@"payed_from"]] : [self.dfDetail dateFromString:self.serverData[@"payed_from"]];
    _payedTill = [self.dfBasic dateFromString:self.serverData[@"payed_till"]] == nil ? [self.dfBasic dateFromString:self.serverData[@"payed_till"]] : [self.dfDetail dateFromString:self.serverData[@"payed_till"]];
    _persons = self.serverData[@"persons"] == [NSNull null] ? @"2-3" : self.serverData[@"persons"];
    _price = self.serverData[@"price"] == [NSNull null] ? @(0) : self.serverData[@"price"];
    _price3 = self.serverData[@"price3"] == [NSNull null] ? @(0) : self.serverData[@"price3"];
    _price12 = self.serverData[@"price12"] == [NSNull null] ? @(0) : self.serverData[@"price12"];
    _status = self.serverData[@"status"] == [NSNull null] ? @"not_payed" : self.serverData[@"persons"];
}
```

So, i can create object with simply wrote: `[MenuAPIModel initWithServerData:data];`

Now i subclass NSManagedObject and wonder, how can i subclass this 4 files XCode did create for me, to make constructor like the one above?

Answer (score 2):

You can create kind of helper which can have following implementation (it's just example so I used Swift):

```
static open func createObject <T : NSManagedObject> (_ objectType : T.Type, record : Dictionary<String, Any>? = nil, context : NSManagedObjectContext) -> (T)
{
    let newObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: String(describing: objectType), into: context)

    // Error never occured

    var typedNewObject = newObject as! T

    guard let trueRecord = record
    else
    {
        return typedNewObject
    }

    typedNewObject = updateObject(typedNewObject, record: trueRecord, context: context)

    return typedNewObject
}

static open func updateObject <T : NSManagedObject> (_ object : T, record : Dictionary<String, Any>, context : NSManagedObjectContext) -> (T)
{
    for (key, value) in record
    {
        setValue(value, key: key, object: object)
    }

    return object
}

static public func setValue (_ value : Any, key : String, object : NSManagedObject) -> (Void)
{
    object.setValue(value, forKey: key)
}
```

With such methods you can then type:

```
let myNewObject = Helper.createObject(YourClassName.self, record: yourDictionary, context: yourContext) // Helper, or any other class name you give it.
```

I hope it's close enough to what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand what you want to subclass, but in order to use `CoreData` your models have to subclass `NSManagedObject`, so if you want to subclass a custom model class that you wrote, that class must subclass `NSManagedObject`.

Now, the new XCode templates for `NSManagedObject` creates one class and one category for each model that you declare in `xcdatamodel`. And you would have something like this.

**MenuAPIModel+CoreDataProperties.h**

```
@interface MenuAPIModel (CoreDataProperties) {
}
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *basketId
.....other properties that you have
@end
```

**MenuAPIModel+CoreDataProperties.m**

```
@implementation MenuAPIModel (CoreDataProperties)
@dynamic basketId
@dynamic ....other properties ...
@end
```

**MenuAPIModel.h**

```
@interface MenuAPIModel : NSManagedObject
+(instancetype)initWithServerData:(id)serverData;
@end
```

**MenuAPIModel.m**

```
@implementation MenuAPIModel

 +(instancetype)initWithServerData:(id)serverData {
     NSManagedObjectContext *context = ...get the current context...
     MenuAPIModel *model = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([MenuAPIModel class])inManagedObjectContext:context];
     model.basketId = serverData[@"basket_id"];
     ...other parsing....
     return model;
 }
```

As you can see, you can use those classes & categories created by default by XCode, by adding just one extra method. Just a reminder, `NSManagedObject` can't be created using `alloc] init];`, it has to be created using the `NSManagedObjectContext`.

Comment: i see, you put all logic in API model. But i want to do opposite- create and fill core data model based on completed API Model class. For example, how to create something like [model initWithData:MenuAPIModell instance]; ?

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban You can fill up the core data model as you want, the important part is how you init the code data model (just like i did).